# Django/React - Cookies Stored Under Wrong Domain Name

Tags: reactjs, django, cookies, session-cookies

I'm using CSRF and Session cookies in a Django React project. Everything works great on local development.

I am having an issue with cookies in the production environment.

The backend and frontend are hosted on Heroku under different domains.

When I request a CSRF token from the backend, the token is stored under the domain name from where the backend is hosted. This means my frontend is unable to access the cookies.

If I call the backend APIs directly from the browser, the cookies work fine since they're stored under the same domain name I sent the request to.

I've been struggling to solve the issue, and any help would be appreciated.

```
# settings.py 


SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True

CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "Lax"
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "Lax"

if config("ENVIRONMENT") == "PRODUCTION":
    CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ["https://biz.mysite.tech"]
else:
    CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ["http://localhost:3000"]

CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = ["Content-Type", "X-CSRFToken"]
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

```
// Axios settings in React 

{
  withCredentials: true,
  credentials: "include",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-CSRFToken": cookies.get("csrftoken"),
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by setting

```
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".mydomain.tech"
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".mydomain.tech"
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ".mydomain.tech"
```

Then I made a subdomain so the requests from `frontend.mydomain.tech` were sent to `backend.mydomain.tech`. I was trying to set cookies from a website hosted on an entirely different domain than the frontend - `mydomainbackend.heroku.com` was receiving requests from `frontend.mydomain.tech`.